# Center icons above h3 Bootstrap (Ionicons)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My icons keep going to the left:

```
<section class="section-what-i-do">
    <div class="container">
      <h2>What I do</h2>
      <p class="sub-header" id="learn-more-section">Studying, creating, learning</p>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <i class="ion-ios-monitor-outline icon-large"></i>
          <h3>Computer Science</h3>
        </div>


        <div class="col-md-4">
          <i class="ion-ios-cloudy-outline icon-large"></i>
          <h3>Web development</h3>
        </div>


        <div class="col-md-4">
          <i class="ion-ios-bolt-outline icon-large"></i>
          <h3>Learning new tech</h3>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Css:

```
.icon-large{
  font-size: 350%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
  color: #e74c3c;
}
```

I do not want to use Bootstrap glyphicons, the ionicons fonts look much better to me.
The icons appear to the far left as if there is code that is set to `float: left`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the `text-align:center` on the **parent** div...

You icons are `display:inline` by default so aren't affected by `margin`.

```css
.icon-large {
  font-size: 350%;
  color: #e74c3c;
}

.col-md-4 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section class="section-what-i-do">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>What I do</h2>
    <p class="sub-header" id="learn-more-section">Studying, creating, learning</p>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <i class="ion-ios-monitor-outline icon-large"></i>
        <h3>Computer Science</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```